# How to prevent Prettier from autocompleting code and moving the cursor while I am still typing in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier, autosave

I am trying to get the Prettier formatter in Visual Studio Code to format the code when the file is autosaved, and it does work, however, the code is formatted before I am even done typing and it makes developing more difficult because of this.

For example, if I type in an h2 tag it drags the cursor to a weird spot, when I type in color for example, Prettier will autocomplete the CSS and place my cursor to the right of the ";" so the code looks like this:

```css
h2 {
color: ; /*(on typing "color:" the cursor is dragged here outside of the colon so I have to click back inside of it to type a color)*/
}
```

How can I have the document autosave itself so I don't potentially lose my work, but also have the formatter kick in shortly after to format the code when I am finished typing? I don't want to have to manually save the document or manually format it. Is this achievable? I am using the VS Code autosave setting.

Comment: I think the autosave part is a misleading part of the question; it sounds like your real issue is not with saving but with Prettier hijacking your cursor while you are typing.

Comment: are you sure this is the Prettier extension's doing? If you disable the Prettier extension and accept other CSS suggestions, does this still happen? Does the behaviour change if you toggle the `css.completion.completePropertyWithSemicolon` setting?